# how to check if a cell is empty in openpyxl python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm making a conditional statement in `openpyxl` Python to check if a cell is empty. Here's my code:

```
newlist = []
looprow = 1
print ("Highest col",readex.get_highest_column())
getnewhighcolumn = readex.get_highest_column()        
for i in range(0, lengthofdict):
    prevsymbol = readex.cell(row = looprow,column=getnewhighcolumn).value
    if prevsymbol == "None":
        pass
    else:
        newstocks.append(prevsymbol)
        looprow += 1
    #print (prevsymbol)
print(newlist)
```

I tried `if prevsymbol == "":` and `if prevsymbol == null:` to no avail.

Comment: can you print prevsymbol and show here?

Comment: What is "lengthofdict"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You compare `prevsymbol` with `str` "None", not `None` object. Try

```
if prevsymbol == None:
```

Also here

```
prevsymbol = readex.cell(row = looprow,column=getnewhighcolumn).value
```

you use `looprow` as row index. And you increment `looprow` only if `cell.value` is not empty. Here

```
newstocks.append(prevsymbol)
```

you use `newstocks` instead of `newlist`. Try this code

```
newlist = []
print ("Highest col",readex.get_highest_column())
getnewhighcolumn = readex.get_highest_column()        
for i in range(0, lengthofdict):
    prevsymbol = readex.cell(row = i+1,column=getnewhighcolumn).value
    if prevsymbol is not None:
        newlist.append(prevsymbol)
print(newlist)
```

Comment: @Newboy11 Or add line `print(prevsymbol )` before `if` condition and post results

Comment: Here's some of the result:  one, None, None, None, None, None, '100', '200', '67', '300'. my input data is in excel in a column mixed with not empty and empty cells. I just want to get the non empty cells

Comment: @Newboy11 If all works fine you could check my answer as right answer)

Answer (score 0):

Take the quotes away from the None.

```
if prevsymbol is None:
```

This is the python equivalent of checking if something is equal to null.

Comment: @Newboy11 I can't find anything in the openpyxl documentation that tells you what it returns for an empty cell.  Is there any way you can tell me what happens if you print `prevsymbol` on an empty cell?